# local module import not working - unresolved reference

Tags: python

Cant figure out why my local modeule/ file import suddenly isnt working anymore. Here is an example where it is clearly visible that both .py files are in the same directory but still I receive an error that there is no such module lists_loop.

I tried creating two completely new py files in the same directory and import one to other. The same error appeared. What could be the cause of this?
I am trying to import a file called lists_loop. When I run the python program I get such an error in cmd:

```
    from lists_loop import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lists_loop'
```

However in the screenshot you can see that they are in the same folder:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `from .lists_loop import *` instead of `from lists_loop import *`

Comment: Seemed to have worked. Any idea why without . it didnt work? Day before everything went well and I didnt update anything. Also I opened up a completely new project and there the imports worked well without.

Answer (score 0):

You can use importlib and try

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module("module")
```

Answer (score 0):

did you define any classes in lists_loop.py? if not then

```
import lists_loop
```

then use the "." to reference any method inside, e.g. lists_loop.myfunction()